# How can I access the data inside this JSON?

Tags: javascript

```
var USER_DETAILS= {
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "john",
            "passwd": "xyz",
            "email": "j@g.com",
            "contact": "87685778",
            "lastLogin": "Sun Aug 24 2014 23:30:54 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "peter",
            "passwd": "xyz",
            "email": "p@g.com",
            "contact": "09820984",
            "lastLogin": "Sun Aug 24 2014 23:41:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "s",
            "passwd": "123",
            "email": "s@g.com",
            "contact": "3435",
            "lastLogin": "Mon Aug 25 2014 00:05:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "y",
            "passwd": "k",
            "email": "j@jhj.com",
            "contact": "87685778",
            "lastLogin": "Mon Aug 25 2014 00:12:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "johny",
            "passwd": "234",
            "email": "lkj@g.com",
            "contact": "34543",
            "lastLogin": "Mon Aug 25 2014 00:20:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this jason data now I need to access the name "John". I have tried accessing it like
`USER_DETAILS.details[i].name` but I am getting error `USER_DETAILS.details is undefined`.

Here is my rest of the code for accessing JSON

```
function check_details()
{
var users=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('USER_DETAILS'));
for (var key in users)
  {
  alert(users.details[0].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Then either the structure is different or you didn't parse the JSON. What does `typeof USER_DETAILS` return? (Note that what you posted is a JavaScript object, not JSON).

Comment: Can you use chrome development tool to inspect what's in the USER_DETAILS before you access USER_DETAILS.details[i].name? Are you trying to access an item out of index?

Comment: No I am accessing element at 0th index

Comment: is there anything else between creating the variable and accessing it that might be altering it? i cant see any problems right now, fiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/twtLh2zp/1/

Comment: Remove the `for...in` loop or use `users[key]`, depending on what `users` is.

Comment: See I have parsed JSON

Comment: Yes, but what's up with the `for in` loop? You are nor even using `key`. Do you know what `for in` does?

Comment: Yeah it gives us one element at a time inside variable key. right? so what is the best way to access this JSON?

Comment: @John you need to loop over the `users.details` object properly, posted a response for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function check_details()
{
    var users=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('USER_DETAILS'));
    for (var user of users.details)
    {
        console.log(user.name);
    }
}
```

You're trying to loop over `users` which only has one object `details`, so you need to loop through the `users.details` object to get all the users

[jsfiddle demo (without using localStorage)](http://jsfiddle.net/ec4j9vyh/)

For reference, documentation about [for...of loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is on MSDN.

Comment: Please use a normal `for` loop to iterate over arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
USER_DETAILS.details[0].name
```

`USER_DETAILS` it is an object with a property `details` that is an Array and it `'John'` is in the first instance of your array.

All together works fine on my end like this:

```
var USER_DETAILS= /* your sample code */;
console.log( USER_DETAILS.details[0].name);
```

Comment: When I debug the code like you said it shows USER_DETAILS.details undefined

Comment: This should work unless you have other problems in your code.
Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: The OP already said in his question that this didn't work for him.

Comment: @FelixKling OP is using `i`, I do not know what that is but I do know 0 exists.

Comment: It doesn't matter which index is used if `USER_DETAILS.details` is undefined.

Comment: @FelixKling this `USER_DETAILS.details[8].name` will also return `undefined` btw, so the index matters

Comment: Yes, but that's not the error the OP is talking about. As I said, if `details` is undefined, suggesting to use 0 instead of i doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @FelixKling Well I think it is error as it is the only way I can think of to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

error **USER_DETAILS.details is undefined**, because of a **syntax error** in your JSON String, missing ' and ''...

- Yours: ={"details":[{"name":"john",...
- Correct: ='{"details":[''{"name":"John",...

**This is a working example**

```
var USER_DETAILS = '{"details":[' +
'{"name":"John","passwd":"1234", "email":"john@gmail.com" },' +

'{"name":"Anna","passwd":"5678", "email":"anna@gmail.com" },' +

'{"name":"Peter","passwd":"9945", "email":"peter@gmail.com" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(USER_DETAILS);
document.getElementById("paragraphid").innerHTML =
obj.details[0].name + " " + obj.details[0].email;
```

**Best Practice:**

- Indent and concatenate your JSON String (+) per entity/row to
  distinguish the individual properties and values for easy readability

Comment: As you can see, the data is actually loaded from `localStorage`, so what you posted is not relevant to the problem.